# Raycast not capturing all Vector coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject that occupies the whole screen just for testing purposes. I'm drawing a line btw. What I'm trying to achieve is if the mouse position hits a gameobject it will store the vector2 coordinates in a list. But raycast is not storing all the coordinates. Below is my code

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

            Vector2 Pos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

            if(!mousePositions.Contains(Pos))
                mousePositions.Add(Pos);


            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos), out RaycastHit hit))
            {
                Vector2 textureCoord = hit.textureCoord;

                int pixelX = (int)(textureCoord.x * _templateDirtMask.width);
                int pixelY = (int)(textureCoord.y * _templateDirtMask.height);

                Vector2Int paintPixelPosition = new Vector2Int(pixelX, pixelY);

                if (!linePositions.Contains(paintPixelPosition))
                    linePositions.Add(paintPixelPosition);

                foreach (Vector2Int pos in linePositions)
                {
                    int pixelXOffset = pos.x - (_brush.width / 2);
                    int pixelYOffset = pos.y - (_brush.height / 2);

                    for (int x = 0; x < _brush.width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < _brush.height; y++)
                        {
                            _templateDirtMask.SetPixel(
                                pixelXOffset + x,
                                pixelYOffset + y,
                                Color.black
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                _templateDirtMask.Apply();
            }
    }
}
```

Everytime I checked the element count mousePositions are always greater than linePositions. I don't know what's causing this

Answer (score 2):

> the element count mousePositions are always greater than linePosition

well it is quite simple: In

```
 int pixelX = (int)(textureCoord.x * _templateDirtMask.width);
 int pixelY = (int)(textureCoord.y * _templateDirtMask.height);
```

you are casting to `int` and cut off any decimals after the comma (basically like doing `Mathf.FloorToInt`).

So you can totally have multiple mouse positions which result in float pixel positions like e.g.

```
1.2, 1.2
1.4, 1.7
1.02, 1.93
...
```

all these will map to

```
Vector2Int paintPixelPosition = new Vector2Int(1, 1);
```

---

Besides, you might want to look at some better line drawing algorithms like e.g. [this simple one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878974/7111561)

And then note that calling `SetPixel` repeatedly is quite expensive. You want to do a single `SetPixels` call like e.g.

```
var pixels = _templateDirtMask.GetPixels();

foreach (Vector2Int pos in linePositions)
{
    int pixelXOffset = pos.x - (_brush.width / 2);
    int pixelYOffset = pos.y - (_brush.height / 2);

    for (int x = 0; x < _brush.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _brush.height; y++)
        {
            pixels[(pixelXOffset + x) + (pixelYOffset + y) * _templateDirtMask.width] = Color.black;
        }
    }
}

_templateDirtMask.SetPixels(pixels);
_templateDirtMask.Apply();
```

Comment: I found a problem I think there's a limit in getpixels cause I'm having an error "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: yeah you probably make sure the index doesn't go `<0`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there is really could be a case, when several elements from `mousePositions` are associated with one elment from `linePositions`.

Rough example: your texture resolution is only 1x1px. In this case you `linePositons` will contain only one element. And this element will be associated with all elements from `mosePositions`.

So, relation of the number of elements in these lists depends on relation of your texture and screen resolutions.